# Can't return string from function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, which displays 2 alerts:

```
function GetDepartment(){
    var dept;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'return_string.asmx/GetDepartment',
        data: '{}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( department ) {

            if( department.d[0] ) {

                dept = department.d[0].code;
                alert( dept );

            } else {

                alert ( "null" );

            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {

             var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
             alert(err.Message) ;

        }
    });

    return dept;
}

alert( GetDepartment() );
```

The first alert displays `undefined` and the second alert displays `MKTG`

Why is the first alert displaying `undefined` and how do I get both to display `MKTG`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will work the way you want it to only if your AJAX call is synchronous. For this you can specify `async: false` in your AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'return_string.asmx/GetDepartment',
    ...
    async: false, /* new */
    ...
});
```

Even better, restructure your app so that the AJAX call can proceed asynchronously without blocking the UI thread and can issue a callback to continue your app-specific processes.

ie. something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'return_string.asmx/GetDepartment',
    ...
    success: yourCallbackFunction,
    ...
});

// callback
function yourCallbackFunction(data) {
    // do stuff that depends on data
}
```

Comment: This is true, but it should be noted that synchronous ajax is a really bad idea unless one is absolutely desperate.

Comment: Yes, totally, i was coming to that. Edit in progress.